# Populate Form Element Values based on existing Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, html, javascript

I am trying to convert an Excel UserForm into Google Sheets where the user can create, update or delete entries in existing sheet based on the input form values. I started with selecting a value and display the editable version of it on a textbox. I tried figuring out what is wrong with the value I pass, it is just always displaying the last value and seems not to loop through.

[image]
*In this example I wanted to fill the form with details from ID 3.*

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,'Form');  
}

function getTextList(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetText = ss.getSheetByName('Text');
  var sheetTextLastRow = sheetText.getLastRow();
  var sheetTextRange = sheetText.getRange("B2:B" + sheetTextLastRow).getValues();
  return sheetTextRange;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectText" size="5">
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="newText" placeholder="New Text Replacement">
    <select id="textCategory" placeholder="Category">
    </select>
    <select id="textLanguage" placeholder="Language">
    </select>
    <textarea id="textDesc" rows="10" cols="60" placeholder="Description">
    </textarea>
  </body>
  <script>         
         function onSuccess(textValues) {
            var select = document.getElementById("selectText");
            var textOptions = textValues;
            for(var i = 0; i < textOptions.length; i++) {
                var textOpt = textOptions[i];
                var textElement = document.createElement("option");
                textElement.textContent = textOpt;
                textElement.value = textOpt;
                select.appendChild(textElement);
                textElement.onclick = function textClick(textDesc){
                    var selectDesc = document.getElementById("newText");   
                    selectDesc.value = textElement.value;                   
                    };

            }

          }

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
              .getTextList();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The values should have been shown with:
`selectDesc.value = textDesc.target.value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I was just using a wrong variable.
The values should have been shown with:

```
selectDesc.value = textDesc.target.value;
```